# How do I get folders in my Visual Studio solution to appear on my server when I deploy (iis7, asp.net mvc4)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

This seems so rudimentary that I am slightly ashamed to ask, but here I am anyway. I have a fairly typical ASP.NET MVC4 solution. In there I have a couple of folder in the root directory where I am storing some logs and files. In particular I have one page that will list all the .xml files in this directory:

```
/ErrorLogs/
```

Running locally this code works like a charm:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < 50 && i < dir.GetFiles().Count(); i++)
 {
     <tr>
         <td>
              @dir.GetFiles()[i].LastWriteTime
         </td>
         <td>
              <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Home", new { area = "Admin", fileName = @dir.GetFiles()[i].FullName })"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></a>
         </td>
     </tr>   
 }
```

Once I deploy the application (Windows Server 2008, IIS 7), I get an error when I navigate to the page. Presumably because when I navigate to the folder on the server in inetpub/wwwroot/mysite the folders are not there.

In the properties of the folder in VS I only see 'Folder Name' and 'Namespace Provider' in there.

How can I get the folder to copy over when I deploy?

Comment: Why don't you just check for the existence of the folders and create them if not found on start-up?

Comment: Hmm... that's a pretty good idea actually. these folders are going to be interacted with by some background workers, so would you say the best place to make sure those folders exist is in that code, or the global.asax?

Comment: Will the IIS process have modify access to this folder?

Comment: @roryWoods Most likely. I think at least. The ErrorLog folder doesn't look like it will (I just manually published the folder so it was there and I can access the page). The other folder is going to have a .csv put in there every time a quartz.net job runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this folder is in the MVC *project* and not the *solution* you could add a file to the project within the folder and set the Build Action property to Content.

Comment: and I would have to set that in the .csproj file?

Comment: Add the folder in Visual Studio which adds it to the csproj file.

Comment: This is what we had to do for folders that we want to get created when we publish.  We included a "_doNotRemove.txt" file in our project

Comment: As @Tommy said make use your folder is not empty by putting some dummy file in it so that when you deploy that folder does not get ignored.